# How can I remove None elements from list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a = [[None, None, None],
     [None, None, None],
     [40.069, 18.642, 1.0],
     [41.18, 19.467, 1.0],
     [None, None, None]]
```

I want this to be like this. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

```
b = [[40.069, 18.642, 1.0], [41.18, 19.467, 1.0]]
```

Comment: To me, this is not clear. will you remove `[None, 1.0,None]`? As I think it would result in different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
filtered = list(filter(any, a))
```

Comment: This would exclude lists such as `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`, which should be kept.

Answer (score 2):

The following does exactly what you said you wanted (including keeping any sublist that wasn't all `None`, even though you didn't show one like that in your sample data):

```
a = [[None, None, None],
     [None, None, None],
     [40.069, 18.642, 1.0],
     [41.18, 19.467, 1.0],
     [None, None, None],
     [0, 0, 0],  # added all int zeros
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # added all float zeros
     [42.13, None, 1.5]]  # added mixture

b = []
for sublist in a:
    cleaned = [elem for elem in sublist if elem is not None]
    if len(cleaned):  # anything left?
        b.append(cleaned)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[40.069, 18.642, 1.0], 
 [41.18, 19.467, 1.0], 
 [0, 0, 0], 
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [42.13, 1.5]]
```

#### Update

If you have Python 3.8+ you can do it very succinctly using an [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) along with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
b = [cleaned for sublist in a
        if (cleaned := [elem for elem in sublist if elem is not None])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 b = [i for i in a if i.count(None) != len(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for lst in a:
 if all(x is None for x in lst):
    pass
 else:
    b.append(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your sub-lists will either be lists of `None` values or lists of float values.  This means that you can use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter list `a` by checking if the first item of each list is `None`:

```
>>> a = [[None, None, None],
...      [None, None, None],
...      [40.069, 18.642, 1.0],
...      [41.18, 19.467, 1.0],
...      [None, None, None]]
>>> b = [x for x in a if x[0] is not None]
>>> b
[[40.069, 18.642, 1.0], [41.18, 19.467, 1.0]]
>>>
```